# Generic ITypedList bound to a WinForms DataGridView: all rows show first item

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a list of items which contain a dynamic property.

The goal is to have classes with defined properties, but also allow setting new properties to its instances on the fly. One sample is the 'MyDynamicObject' class in the code below.

The list (an instance of 'DynamicITypedList' in the code below) is then bound to a DataGridView, which will show and bind every property of the list items to a column.

The problem I face is: as soon as I make the 'DynamicITypedList' class implement 'ITypedList', all the rows in the DataGridView show the properties of the first item in the list !
If I don't make the list class implement 'ITypedList' (comment out 'ITypedList' at the very end of the code below), the dynamically added properties values are not shown (because the specific GetItemProperties() is not called), but all rows show up in the DataGridView...

Can you please drive me towards a solution ?

Here is the calling code, ready to run in a WinForm containing one "datagridView1" control:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Tests
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttonITypedList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyDynamicObject myDynamicObject1 = new MyDynamicObject();
            myDynamicObject1.Id = 1;
            myDynamicObject1.AsDynamic.NewProperty = "NEWPROP1";
            MyDynamicObject myDynamicObject2 = new MyDynamicObject();
            myDynamicObject2.Id = 2;
            DynamicITypedList<MyDynamicObject> myDynamicObjectDynamicITypedList = new DynamicITypedList<MyDynamicObject>();
            myDynamicObjectDynamicITypedList.Add(myDynamicObject1);
            myDynamicObjectDynamicITypedList.Add(myDynamicObject2);
            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
            bindingSource.DataSource = myDynamicObjectDynamicITypedList;
            bindingSource.AllowNew = true;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> property in myDynamicObject1.Data.Properties)
            {
                DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dynamicPropertyColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                dynamicPropertyColumn.DataPropertyName = property.Key;
                dynamicPropertyColumn.HeaderText = property.Key;
                dynamicPropertyColumn.Name = property.Key;
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dynamicPropertyColumn);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below are the classes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Tests
{
    public interface IMyDynamic
    {
        MyDynamic Data { get; set; }
        IEnumerable<string> GetDynamicMemberNames();
    }

    public class MyDynamic : DynamicObject, IDynamicMetaObjectProvider
    {
        object Instance { get; set; }
        Type InstanceType { get; set; }
        Dictionary<string, MemberInfo> MemberInfos { get; set; }
        PropertyInfo[] instancePropertyInfo;

        PropertyInfo[] InstancePropertyInfo
        {
            get
            {
                if (instancePropertyInfo == null && Instance != null)
                    instancePropertyInfo = Instance.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
                return instancePropertyInfo;
            }
        }

        public MyDynamic()
        {
            Initialize(this);
        }

        public MyDynamic(object instance)
        {
            Initialize(instance);
        }

        public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> GetProperties(bool includeInstanceProperties = false)
        {
            if (includeInstanceProperties && Instance != null)
            {
                foreach (var prop in this.InstancePropertyInfo)
                    yield return new KeyValuePair<string, object>(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(Instance, null));
            }

            foreach (var key in this.Properties.Keys)
                yield return new KeyValuePair<string, object>(key, this.Properties[key]);

        }

        public override IEnumerable<string> GetDynamicMemberNames()
        {
            foreach (var prop in GetProperties(true))
                yield return prop.Key;
        }

        public Dictionary<string, object> Properties { get; private set; }

        public object this[string key]
        {
            get
            {
                try
                {
                    //Try to get from properties collection first
                    return Properties[key];
                }
                catch (KeyNotFoundException)
                {
                    //Try reflection on instanceType
                    object result = null;
                    if (GetProperty(Instance, key, out result))
                        return result;
                    //Nope doesn't exist
                    //throw;  //Preserve the stack trace
                    return null;
                }
            }
            set
            {
                if (Properties.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    Properties[key] = value;
                    return;
                }
                //Check instance for existance of type first
                var miArray = InstanceType.GetMember(key, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.GetProperty);
                if (miArray != null && miArray.Length > 0)
                    SetProperty(Instance, key, value);
                else
                    Properties[key] = value;
            }
        }

        protected virtual void Initialize(object instance)
        {
            Instance = instance;
            if (instance != null)
                InstanceType = instance.GetType();
            Properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        }

        public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
        {
            result = null;
            //First check the Properties collection for member
            if (Properties.Keys.Contains(binder.Name))
            {
                result = Properties[binder.Name];
                return true;
            }
            //Next check for Public properties via Reflection
            if (Instance != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    return GetProperty(Instance, binder.Name, out result);
                }
                catch { }
            }
            //Failed to retrieve a property
            result = null;
            return false;
        }

        public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
        {
            //First check to see if there's a native property to set
            if (Instance != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (SetProperty(Instance, binder.Name, value))
                        return true;
                }
                catch { }
            }
            //No match - set or add to dictionary
            Properties[binder.Name] = value;
            return true;
        }

        protected bool GetProperty(object instance, string name, out object result)
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = this;
            if (MemberInfos == null)
            {
                MemberInfos = new Dictionary<string, MemberInfo>();
                MemberInfo[] memberInfos = InstanceType.GetMember(name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.SetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance);
                foreach (MemberInfo instanceMemberInfo in InstanceType.GetMembers())
                    MemberInfos.Add(instanceMemberInfo.Name, instanceMemberInfo);
            }
            result = null;
            MemberInfo propertyMemberInfo;
            if (!MemberInfos.TryGetValue(name, out propertyMemberInfo))
                return false;
            if (propertyMemberInfo.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
            {
                result = ((PropertyInfo)propertyMemberInfo).GetValue(instance, null);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        protected bool SetProperty(object instance, string name, object value)
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = this;
            if (MemberInfos == null)
            {
                MemberInfos = new Dictionary<string, MemberInfo>();
                MemberInfo[] memberInfos = InstanceType.GetMember(name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.SetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance);
                foreach (MemberInfo instanceMemberInfo in InstanceType.GetMembers())
                    MemberInfos.Add(instanceMemberInfo.Name, instanceMemberInfo);
            }
            MemberInfo propertyMemberInfo;
            if (!MemberInfos.TryGetValue(name, out propertyMemberInfo))
                return false;
            if (propertyMemberInfo.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
            {
                ((PropertyInfo)propertyMemberInfo).SetValue(Instance, value, null);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public /*abstract*/ class MyDynamicObject : MyDynamic, IMyDynamic
    {
        public MyDynamic Data
        {
            get { return data; }
            set { data = dynamicData = value; }
        }

        public dynamic AsDynamic
        {
            get { return dynamicData; }
        }

        public Int64 Id { get { return AsDynamic.Id; } set { AsDynamic.Id = value; } }

        MyDynamic data;
        dynamic dynamicData;

        public MyDynamicObject() : this(new MyDynamic())
        { }

        public MyDynamicObject(MyDynamic data)
        {
            Data = data;
            TypeDescriptor.AddProvider(new MyDynamicTypeDescriptionProvider(), this); //Data);
        }
    }

    public class IMyDynamicTypeDescriptor : ICustomTypeDescriptor
    {
        private readonly IMyDynamic m_Instance;

        public IMyDynamicTypeDescriptor(object instance)
        {
            if (instance is MyDynamicObject)
                m_Instance = (MyDynamicObject)instance;
            else if (instance is IMyDynamic)
                m_Instance = (IMyDynamic)instance;
        }

        public string GetComponentName()
        {
            return TypeDescriptor.GetComponentName(this, true);
        }

        public EventDescriptor GetDefaultEvent()
        {
            return TypeDescriptor.GetDefaultEvent(this, true);
        }

        public string GetClassName()
        {
            return TypeDescriptor.GetClassName(this, true);
        }

        public EventDescriptorCollection GetEvents(Attribute[] attributes)
        {
            return TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(this, attributes, true);
        }

        EventDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetEvents()
        {
            return TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(this, true);
        }

        public TypeConverter GetConverter()
        {
            return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(this, true);
        }

        public object GetPropertyOwner(PropertyDescriptor pd)
        {
            return m_Instance;
        }

        public AttributeCollection GetAttributes()
        {
            return TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(this, true);
        }

        public object GetEditor(Type editorBaseType)
        {
            return TypeDescriptor.GetEditor(this, editorBaseType, true);
        }

        public PropertyDescriptor GetDefaultProperty()
        {
            return null;
        }

        PropertyDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties()
        {
            return ((ICustomTypeDescriptor)this).GetProperties(new Attribute[0]);
        }

        public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
        {
            return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(
                m_Instance.Data.Properties.Keys
                          .Select(x => new MyDynamicPropertyDescriptor(m_Instance, x))
                          .ToArray<PropertyDescriptor>());
        }

    }

    public class MyDynamicPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
    {
        private readonly IMyDynamic m_Instance;
        private readonly string m_Name;

        public MyDynamicPropertyDescriptor(IMyDynamic instance, string name)
            : base(name, null)
        {
            m_Instance = instance;
            m_Name = name;
        }

        public override Type PropertyType
        {
            get
            {
                if (m_Instance.Data[m_Name] != null)
                    return m_Instance.Data[m_Name].GetType();
                else
                {
                    //...
                    return typeof(string);
                }
            }
        }

        public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
        {
            m_Instance.Data[m_Name] = value;
        }

        public override object GetValue(object component)
        {
            return m_Instance.Data[m_Name];
        }

        public override bool IsReadOnly
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public override Type ComponentType
        {
            get { return null; }
        }

        public override bool CanResetValue(object component)
        {
            return false;
        }

        public override void ResetValue(object component)
        { }

        public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component)
        {
            return false;
        }

        public override string Category
        {
            get { return string.Empty; }
        }

        public override string Description
        {
            get { return string.Empty; }
        }
    }

    public class MyDynamicTypeDescriptionProvider : TypeDescriptionProvider
    {
        private static readonly TypeDescriptionProvider m_Default = TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(typeof(ExpandoObject));

        public MyDynamicTypeDescriptionProvider() : base(m_Default)
        { }

        public override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetTypeDescriptor(Type objectType, object instance)
        {
            var defaultDescriptor = base.GetTypeDescriptor(objectType, instance);
            return (instance == null ? defaultDescriptor : new IMyDynamicTypeDescriptor(instance));
        }
    }

    public class DynamicITypedList<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, /*List<T>, IList<T>,*/ ITypedList where T : IMyDynamic, new()
    {
        public string GetListName(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetItemProperties(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
        {
            return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this.FirstOrDefault());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

this is not really an answer to the question directly, but...

I had the same task some days ago. Bind dynamic objects to a datagrid.

My solution is:

- Add the columns to the datagrid manually
- Set the databinding-properties manually
- Use BindingSource, bind this BindingSource to your List **then** bind your grid to the bindingsource

Be sure to do all of this in the correct order, because if you don't, your dynamic properties are unknown to the grid/bindingsource and therefore won't be shown.

**I don't remember the exact order of all of this**, maybe you should try around a little with my hints and come back and ask further?

Comment: to whomever downvoted this answer: please leave a comment. i don't understand your downvote. Thanks